# How is each process pinned to a specific core by scheduler (Linux)

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

I am now studying about the scheduler of Linux. Regarding CPU core affinity, I would like to know the following:

1) How is each process(thread) pinned to a core?

there is a system call `sched_setaffinity` to change the core affinity on which a process is executed. But internally, when a process(or a thread) is generated, how does the default Linux scheduler assign the process(thread) to a specific core? I modified `sched_setaffinity` system call to dump information about the task being moved from one core to another.

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%d %d %ld %lu %s\n", current->pid, current->tgid,
                                       current->state, current->cpus_allowed,
                                       current->comm);
```

It seems that there is no dump of the above information in `/var/log/messages`. So the default scheduler pins each process in a different way, but I cannot figure out how.

2) Is it possible to get core ID by PID or other information?

This is what I want to implement inside of Linux kernel. In `task_struct`, there is a member called `cpus_allowed`. But this is a mask for setting affinity, not core ID. I want to retrieve a data identifying the core on which specified process is running.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Each CPU has its own runqueue, AFAIK we can find out current CPU of a process by looking for which runqueue it belongs to. Given `task_struct *p`, we can get its runqueue by `struct rq = task_rq(p)`, and struct rq has a field named [cpu](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.35/kernel/sched.c#L510), I guess this should be the answer.

I have not tried this in practice, just read some code online, and am not quite sure it it will work or not. Wish it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will let you know after I try this method.

Comment: Note that this is racy - the task could be migrated from one runqueue to another underneath you.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the CPU ID on which a thread is running by using its task_struct:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>

task_struct *p;
int cpu_id = task_cpu(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Field 39 in `/proc/pid/stat` tells the current core/cpu of the process.

e.g.:

```
#cat /proc/6128/stat
6128 (perl) S 3390 6128 3390 34821 6128 4202496 2317 268 0 0 1621 59 0 0 16 0 1 0 6860821 10387456 1946 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 128 0 18446744073709551615 0 0 17 8 0 0 0
```

Process 6128 is running on core 8.

Answer (score 0):

CPU core affinity is OS specific. The OS knows how to do this, you do not have to. You could run into all sorts of issues if you specified which core to run on, some of which could actually slow the process down.

In Linux Kernel, the data structure associated with processes task_struct contains cpu_allowed bitmask field. This contains n bits one for each of n processors in the machine. A machine with four physical core's would have four bits. If those CPU core's were hyperthread-enabled they would have an eight-bit bitmask. If a given bit is set for a given process, that process may run on the associated core. Therefore, if a process is allowed to run on any core and allowed to migrate across processors as needed, the bitmask would be entirely 1s. This is in fact, the default state for processes under Linux. For example,

```
PID  2441: PRIO 0, POLICY N: SCHED_NORMAL, NICE 0, AFFINITY 0x3
```

the process 2441 has a CPU affinity of 0x3, which means it can used in Core0 and Core1.

The applications can also specify/set the affinity using Kernel API sched_set_affinity() by altering the bitmask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is different what I want. I was wondering if my description is misleading...

First of all, I don't use `sched_setaffinity` system call (not sched_set_affinity but sched_setaffinity) because I don't create an application running in user space.

Comment: Second of all, `cpus_allowed` (not cpu_allowed) field is not sufficient information to identify the CPU core on which the process is running. cpus_allowed is set as 1 by default so that the process is likely to move all available cores. If there is any field/method telling the location where the process is running, this is what I really want to know.